# 2000s anime where the main character collects round magic stones with a bracelet

Tags: story-identification, anime, magic

I think it came out between 2000-2010. Saw this in anime club in high school. Can't remember some details. The main character finds a bracelet, gets these round stones, and the bracelet collects them? For magic abilities? Not sure? Please help!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. A bit more info would be really useful here. Please take a look at the prompts in [this thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question), then [edit] your question to add any further details you can think of. It'd be particularly helpful to know what the main characters looked like. Also, did you actually watch this between 2000 and 2010, or more recently? If more recently, then when?

Answer (score 4):

The only noughties anime that comes to mind which features adding stones to a bracelet is [Night Wizard](https://www.anime-planet.com/anime/night-wizard) (2007).

> Renji, along with his childhood friend Kureha and the serious Akari, are tasked with protecting Elis Shiho, who has been chosen to collect seven mystical jewels in order to protect the world against an imminent Emulator invasion.

[Elis Shihou](https://myanimelist.net/character/5397/Elis_Shihou) has to collect seven “Jewels of Virtue” to complete her bracelet Ain Soph Aur, which can also split and enlarge to form shields.

[image: Elis Shihou]
[image: Ain Soph Aur]
[image: Ain Soph Aur enlarged]
[image: Anzelotte and Jewels]